# What's the difference between `git fetch origin` and `git fetch git://127.0.0.1/`

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

I am experimenting with git and have created a repository in `~/A` containing only a master branch.

I have then cloned this repository into `~/B` (by starting a `git daemon` in `~/A` and running `git clone git://127.0.0.1/`).

I then created a new `test` branch in `~/A` and tried to get that branch in `~/B`. However, `git fetch git://127.0.0.1/` only showed

```
From git://127.0.0.1
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

To get the new branch I ended up doing `git fetch`, which as far as I understand is equivalent to `git fetch origin`. In any case, both of these give me

```
From git://127.0.0.1
 * [new branch]      test       -> origin/test
```

after which I can start working on the `test` branch in `~/B` by doing `git checkout test`.

**How is it possible that `git fetch git://127.0.0.1/` and `git fetch origin` have different results, when `git remote -v` shows**

```
origin  git://127.0.0.1/ (fetch)
origin  git://127.0.0.1/ (push)
```

The daemon shows the same request for all commands, namely

```
[20291] Extended attribute "host": 127.0.0.1
[20291] Request upload-pack for '/'
```

Comment: Your Git URL does not look correct, [see here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#URLS).  I think it should be ending in `.git`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I got that part from https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/9af3b9796d7423cd0e8e1d419fcea9fc Note that `git clone git://127.0.0.1/` does not cause any problem

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not required that the URL ends in `.git`. That's only a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git fetch origin` you are asking git to look up the configuration for your remote named origin, fetch from the configured URL and write any fetchspec mapping to store the remote’s information in remote tracking branches (eg mapping your `refs/remotes/origin/master` to the remote’s `refs/heads/master`).

When you run `git fetch <url>`, you bypass the remote configuration.  git does not try to match the url to a remote and use the remote configuration.  (Indeed that would be ambiguous, you can have multiple remotes with the same URL, which might be useful for configuring different fetch specs).

Instead, `git fetch <url>` will fetch from the specified url directly, and put the remote’s `HEAD` into your `FETCH_HEAD` file.  Since there is no remote, it does not update remote tracking branches.  You can inspect `FETCH_HEAD` to see what you’ve fetched, however it’s much easier to fetch with a remote instead of a url.

Comment: You say "you can have multiple remotes with the same URL, which might be useful for configuring different fetch specs". Where can I investigate these "fetch specs"? I would have guessed `git remote -v` shows me all there is to know about remotes but as mentioned in the question this command only shows URLs

Comment: That's a good question - I don't see an obvious easy command to do it; you can run `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.  (I would have expected a `git remote` command but I don't see one.)